# How would I scroll in chunks instead of smoothly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

In my React app, I have an instance where I don't want to scroll smoothly down the page. Instead, when I scroll, I want to jump to the next section.

If you go to google sheets, the equivalent is that google sheets does not scroll smoothly. Instead, it jumps down row by row.

I don't know if listening via the onScroll method is the right approach because I imagine doing so would still have the user see some smooth scrolling.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/